# React useEffect not working with api call

Tags: reactjs

I want to call an api and get some data in useEffect

```
const Input = () => {
    const data = useRef({})

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('api here')
        const json = await res.json()
        return json.result
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
        fetchData().then(apiData => {
            data.current = apiData
          }) 
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {data &&
                <div className="page-container">
                    <Overview {...data.description}></Overview>
                    <Entries entries={data.entry}></Entries>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

But I didn't get any data from it. data is still an empty object.

I noticed that react may render first and the  fetch data, so I add a {data && ...}, but it still doesn't work.

When I look at the terminal, there's no log "bbbbbbb", it seems that useEffect is not executed.

I also tried some other code like this

```
async function fetchData() {
            axios
              .get(url)
              .then((response) => {
                const json = response.data;
                data.current = json
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
```

But it doesnt work either.

Why this happened? How to do async api call in useEffect? Or there are some better ways to do api calls?

I also use useState rather than useRef, but not work either

I try to put the definition into the useEffect, but not work either

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const res = await fetch('some api here')
            const json = await res.json()
            return json.result
        }
        console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
        fetchData().then(apiData => {
            setData(apiData)
          }) 
    }, [])
```

Comment: Are you sure you have placed the Input component in App.js or anywhere else where it has to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend https://tanstack.com/query/latest
It gives you the tools to handle loading, data, and error states in a straightforward way. Then you can treat data returned, loading, and errors like stateful variables, which simplifies the whole data fetching process.

Answer (score 0):

Use **usestate** to store data

```
const Input = () => {
   const [data, setData] = React.useState([])

    

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
      .get("/api/getData")
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data)
      })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {data && data.length>0 &&
                <div className="page-container">
                    <Overview {...data.description}></Overview>
                    <Entries entries={data.entry}></Entries>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify something because when you call you api in useEffect its only render first time that's why you did not gey the value after fetch the data.

```
const Input = () => {
    const data = useRef({})
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([])

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('api here')
        const json = await res.json()
        return json.result
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData().then(apiData => {
            setData(apiData);
          }) 
    }, [fetchData])

    return (
        <>
            {data &&
                <div className="page-container">
                    <Overview {...data.description}></Overview>
                    <Entries entries={data.entry}></Entries>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `useState` instead of `useRef`. You can know difference between `useRef` and `useState` in the [new react documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/referencing-values-with-refs).

This is a working example using `useState`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=2&is_xml=true"
    );
    const json = await res.json();
    return json;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
    fetchData().then((apiData) => {
      setData(apiData);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data?.length && (
        <div className="page-container">{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can find a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-monad-xmy4ug?file=/src/App.js:0-603)